# How to set a particular bit to 1 in an array of say 16 bits (15:0) and clear the remaining bits at the same time

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

I have an array of let's say 16 bits (15:0). I have a registered 4 bit variable say 'pos' that changes based on other conditions. depending on the value of the variable pos i want to set a bit and clear the remaining bits (0). for eg., if pos=5, bit 5 should become 1 and all others set to 0 (cleared).  0000 0000 0010 0000 is the desired value. this should be synthesizable in system verilog

i am able to set the desired bit but clearing the remaining bits has been a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the logical shift operator to set a bit

```
value = 16'b1 << pos;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. will this clear bits to the right and left of the bit?

Comment: Yes, on a left shift you always get zeros in from the right hand side and the 16'b1 is a number with 15 leading zeros from which you lose some on the left hand side

Answer (score 0):

1) See the other answer with the shift
2) For more complex cases, like if you want to keep the right or left part of another value after or before the 1, you could simply assign the full answer/result out of the 16 possible, with a case statement.
3) You can also use a loop over all bits setting their own logical equation, like 1 if equal to the counter, 0 if above, the source bit if under/else, and so on...

Comment: That seems overly complex. A simpler approach would leverage the example above:

new_value = old_value | (16'b1 << pos);